# OpenMP using loops and array reductions

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, computation

I have written a program as follows:

```
#include "omp.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int i, j, cnt[] = {0,0,0,0};
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int cnt_private[] = {0,0,0,0};
        #pragma omp for private(j)
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= 10 ; i++) {
            for(j = 1 ; j <= 10 ; j++) {
                int l= omp_get_thread_num();
                cnt_private[l]++;         
            }
            #pragma omp critical
            {   
               for(int m=0; m<3; m++){
                   cnt[m] = cnt_private[m];
               }
            }
           printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",i,cnt[0],cnt[1],cnt[2],cnt[3]);
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

It should print the number of times each thread is executed for each i. As only one thread takes a particular i, the expected output should satisfy the sum of each row as 100. But I am getting the output of the form:

```
1 10 0 0 0
2 20 0 0 0
3 30 0 0 0
7 0 0 10 0
8 0 0 20 0
9 0 0 0 0
10 0 0 0 0
4 0 10 0 0
5 0 20 0 0
6 0 30 0 0
```

Where is the problem? Could it be in my fundamental understanding of OpenMP? or is my reduction process wrong?
(I use a GNU gcc compiler and a 4 core machine)
Compilation steps:

```
g++ -fopenmp BlaBla.cpp
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
./a.out
```

Comment: You declared i twice. Not the bug but...

Comment: Each thread gets its own private cnt_private, so it will only ever have entries from its own thread id; and cnt just has a copy of cnt_private's data in it - from which ever thread is running the current `i` index.  So what you have (modulo stopping the `m` loop too early)  is correct.  In particular, you are _not_ doing a reduction on cnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see why the sum of each row should be 100.

You declared `cnt_private` to be private:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    int cnt_private[] = {0,0,0,0};
    // ...
}
```

As such the summation stored to it is not shared between threads. If thread `l` is executed only `cnt_private[l]` will be incremented and all others will be left at zero. Then you assing the content of `cnt_private` to `cnt`, which is not private. You assign every entry that is zero as well!

```
#pragma omp critical
{   
    for(int m=0; m<4; m++){ // I guess you want 'm<4' for the number of threads
        cnt[m] = cnt_private[m];
    }
}
```

With `i` ranging from 0 to 10 and the program using 4 threads, each threads gets 2 to 3 `i`'s. As such I would expect the sum of each column to be either 30(10+20) or 60(10+20+30).

Comment: Yeah I get it now, I had a typo on the m loop...thanks.

Comment: So, the reduction of the array counter is not done accurately? Do I have to make 'cnt' private as well in order to get the expected result?

Comment: I don't know what result you expect, could you elaborate on what the result should look like? Maybe you only want to assign `cnt[l] = cnt_private[l];` or remove cnt_private and use cnt instead.

Comment: I just want to know if reduction on the array was done correctly as we cannot directly use reduction clause on an array variable in C?

Comment: The reduction is done correct, with one small mistake. In the line `cnt[m] = cnt_private[m];` the current thread overrides values calculated by other threads. This is normally not wanted. You normally want `cnt[m] += cnt_private[m];`.